# Does NX dynamic module federation support SSR

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx, angular-module-federation

Does NX dynamic module federation support SSR? If so can you please share any documentation available!!

Reference link or a code snippet to understand the development/deployment.

Somewhere in github forum I read, NX doesnt support dynamic module federation for SSR served MFEs.

Similar problem reference https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10887

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes!

Let's try to create test project follow steps below:

```
npx create-nx-workspace --name=test--preset=apps --nxCloud=skip && cd test
npx nx add @nx/angular 
npx nx g @nx/angular:host apps/host --dynamic --ssr --standalone --style=scss --addTailwind --e2eTestRunner=playwright --projectNameAndRootFormat=as-provided --prefix=host
npx nx g @nx/angular:remote apps/remote-a --host=host --ssr --standalone --style=scss --addTailwind --e2eTestRunner=playwright --projectNameAndRootFormat=as-provided --prefix=remote-a
npx nx g @nx/angular:remote apps/remote-b --host=host --ssr --standalone --style=scss --addTailwind --e2eTestRunner=playwright --projectNameAndRootFormat=as-provided --prefix=remote-b
npx nx serve host --devRemotes=remote-a,remote-b
```

But there is a note here that the serve command will not work properly without devRemotes config